# Windows Universal new CRC16_CCITTFALSE() function

Tags: c#, windows

I am implementing a MVC pattern for a Windows Universal app that needs to talk over a serial port.

My `MainPage.xaml.cs` file contains a function

```
using System.Data.HashFunction.CRCStandards;

public static IMyCommandSender CreateCommandSender()
{
     var crc = new CRC16_CCITTFALSE();
     return new MyCommandSender(crc.ComputeHash);
}
```

I have copied the above lines verbatim from another app (not compiled for Universal).

It seems that `CRC16_CCITTFALSE()` is not under `System.Data.HashFunction.CRCStandards`  under Windows Universal.

It would be great if someone could explain how the above function could be rewritten for Windows Universal.

Comment: An open source library that uses the System.Data namespace, tsk, tsk, tsk.  Most obvious way to get ahead is to just rebuild the library from source.

Comment: @HansPassant - how do I do that ? This is my very first C# project. It would be great if you could explain

Comment: I think what @Hans is saying is that `System.Data.HashFunction` isn't a Microsoft namespace.  It certainly isn't in the documentation.  A Google search suggests that it is a third-party library, which is breaking the rules and inserting its own content into what should be a MS-only space.  My recommendation, if it isn't too late to change tack, is to see if you can find better sample code.  The code you copied those lines from isn't setting a good example for you. :-)